# How to Automate pull request on a regular interval

Tags: git

Is it possible under Windows machines via the sourceTree or other application to Automate pull request on a regular (via a batch file) interval repo..?

Comment: Have a look at [Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569)

Comment: What does it mean "to automate pull request"?  What kind of pull request are you referring to?

Comment: @SvenMarnach I assumed it meant pull a git repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Batch script:***

```
C:\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxxx\Git\bin\sh.exe --login -i -c "/d/backupScript.sh"
```

***Backup script:***

```
PWD=$(pwd);
function welcome() {
   echo "current Dir   : $PWD";
}
function backup_1() {
    cd /d/xxx/xxx/xxx
    echo "backup_1   : $PWD";
    git pull origin master  
}
function backup_2() {
    cd /d/xxx/xxx/xxx
    echo "backup_2   : $PWD";
    git pull origin master      
}
function backup_3() {
    cd /d/xxx/xxx/xxx
    echo "backup_3   : $PWD";
    git pull origin master      
}
function backup_4() {
    cd /d/xxxx/xxxx/xxxxx
    echo "backup_4   : $PWD";
    git pull origin master      
}
backup_1;
backup_2;
backup_3;
backup_4;
echo "See You Soon";
sleep 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows Task Scheduler to start repeating tasks (include batch files) automatically